# What does merging duplicate Leads/Contacts/Account do at the record and related record level?

Tags: lightning-experience, duplicate-management, merge

I am exploring the Duplicate Merge features in Salesforce Lightning Experience. I am wondering exactly what happens when you choose to merge records:

1. Do the merge-from records get deleted?
2. Do the related list records get moved to the merge-to record, even custom lists?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the merge-from records get deleted?

Yes, they are moved to the Recycle Bin (which can as of yet only be seen in Classic).

> Do the related list records get moved to the merge-to record, even custom lists?

Yes, all child records are automatically re-parented. This merge cannot be undone.